# I use to use Jdbc connection to link my external DB. Today it seems there is intermittency in the link, could someone guide me to solve the problem?

Tags: jdbc, connection

My code:
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbString,user, pass);
The error report:
TypeError: Jdbc.getConnection is not a function at conectaMySql

Comment: I have also been seeing this intermittently for the past 24 hours in google app script (GAS) execution. Are you seeing this in GAS or other environment?

Comment: If you can confirm that this is coming from Google App Script I believe I know what the issue is.

Comment: Stewart Whitman - is on GAS environment

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because the scope for `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` has not been approved by the user.

This is required before the application can access JDBC.  Add the scope above to your appscript.json if it is not already and make sure your users accept the new scope.